# Function Pointers and Argurments

Tags: c, pointers, function-pointers

I have been trying to understand a post from geeksforgeeks and am not able to understand a code snippet. Here is the following post:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/returning-a-function-pointer-from-a-function-in-c-cpp/

In this post they give and example code as the following:

Based on the following code

```
#include <stdio.h>
 
int add(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}
 
int subtract(int a, int b) {
    return a - b;
}
 
int (*operation(char op))(int, int) {
    if (op == '+') {
        return &add;
    } else if (op == '-') {
        return &subtract;
    } else {
        return NULL;
    }
}
 
int main() {
    int (*func_ptr)(int, int) = operation('+');
    printf("%d\n", func_ptr(4, 5));
    return 0;
}
```

I'm not understanding how a function be declared like this. Based on my knowledge of function pointers, a function pointer can be declared as such:

```
int func(int x, int y){
     return x*y;
}

int (*func_ptr) (int, int);
func_ptr = &func;
```

The description is not very clear as well from the post:

"In this example, we have two functions called add() and subtract() that take two integer arguments and return an integer value. We also have a function called operation() that takes a character argument op and returns a function pointer to add() or subtract() depending on the value of op. Finally, in main(), we call operation() with ‘+’ as the argument and store the result in a function pointer called func_ptr. We then call func_ptr() with 4 and 5 as arguments and print the result to the console."

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: *"but their is no actual name to the function"* The function is called `operation`. Or what do you mean? Do you understand that the first `(` doesn't begin a parameter list, it's just for grouping? The parameter list is `(char op)`.

Comment: What part is unclear to you? The description from the post details exactly what is coded. Try reading and digesting one sentence at a time.

Comment: This looks like a very simple, clear example.  The function called `operation` returns a pointer to a function, determined by the value passed for `op`.  Is there some question other than this?

Comment: OT: While this code is purely for demonstration purposes, the "loaded gun" that `operation()` could return NULL (not accounted for by the caller) is a bit disconcerting... Also, the `&` is unnecessary in the return statements. Also, the `else` clauses are unnecessary (when "true" means `return`.)

Comment: Sorry guys, I tried editing a little to explain what I don't understand. I'm not really getting how the parameter list is (char op) and then having more parameters as (int, int)

Comment: @KarlGardner "how the parameter list is (char op) ..." --> [operation as function (char) returning pointer to function (int, int) returning int](https://cdecl.org/?q=int+%28*operation%28char%29%29%28int%2C+int%29+).  It, the function, does not have more parameters `(int, int)`.  The `(int, int)` are part of the pointer type, not function parameter list.

Comment: `int (*operation(char op))(int, int)` -> `typedef int fn_t(int,int); fn_t *operation(char op);` or `typeof(int(int,int)) * operation(char op);`. It will make the code far more readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's just how the C syntax works when you want to return a function pointer.

Not sure if this will make it more clear but it tries to explain what the individual parts of the statement means:

```
int (*operation(char op))(int, int) 
      \-------/
        Name of this function

int (*operation(char op))(int, int) 
               \-------/
            Arguments for this function

int (*operation(char op))(int, int) 
    ^^                  ^^        ^
    This function returns a function pointer

int (*operation(char op))(int, int) 
                         \---------/
                              The argument types taken by the function the
                              function pointer points to.

int (*operation(char op))(int, int) 
\-/
 The return type of the function the function pointer points to.
```

The syntax can be simplified using a typedef like:

```
typedef int (*func_pointer)(int, int);

func_pointer operation(char op) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks to both "Support Ukraine" and Fe2O3. I was just about to post another answer about how the way I learned to return a function pointer was the typedef way, but I guess there are two different techniques to do it. I never would have thought that the stuff after the function name would be a part of the return type.

Comment: @KarlGardner And it can get even worse. For fun try this one: `int (*(*operation(char ))(int , int ))(int , int )` What is this function doing. The principle is the same but... yeah, looks strange to start with. ;-)

Comment: @KarlGardner There is this site: https://cdecl.org/ It's not perfect (i.e. sometimes the answer is strange/wrong) but if you use with a little care, it can help a lot when dealing with complex expressions.

Comment: Oh gosh, I guess operation returns a pointer to a function which that function pointer which returns a function pointer? That's my best guess lol

Answer (score 1):

Deconstruction: read from the token in the recommended sequence:

- `operation` // there's the token, now look to the right
- `operation(char op)` // "operation" is a function (taking one `char` argument)
- `(*operation(char op))` // now left. Looks like "operation" returns some kind of pointer
- `(*operation(char op))(int, int)` // Ah! returns a pointer to a function taking two `int`s
- `int (*operation(char op))(int, int) {` // THAT function returns an `int`

It's all there...

You've added your understanding of "how it should look". Notice that this is exactly what appears in `main()` when a pointer to `operation` is defined (and used.)

Answer (score 0):

You must see this thing with something like *algebraic* view ;)

A function is identified by a name declared somewhere. Just like a variable is.

using a `typedef` can make things easier to read, as long as you have many many functions with the same signature. It not always the case. But it can save you a lot of typing.

### EXAMPLE: a Virtual Function Table VFT

I will show another example. My idea here is to illustrate that the `operation` function can be abstracted in an **array**. This is ESSENTIAL in systems programming and **OOP** code in general. Or in the way *javascript* associate functions to events, the so called *callback functions*

This array is called a VFT, Virtual Function Table.

The use of such a thing is much more faster and smarter than writing a thing like the one in `GFG`:

```
int (*operation(char op))(int, int) {
    if (op == '+') {
        return &add;
    } else if (op == '-') {
        return &subtract;
    } else {
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

And why is that?

- `operation()` is itself a function that is being called.
- always tests the same things for the same results
- e.g. `+` will return always `add`
- and only then there will be another function call to the required operation:

```
    int (*func_ptr)(int, int) = operation('+');
    printf("%d\n", func_ptr(4, 5));
```

### a short example

#### the result

```
                Operands are '42' and '17'
                For operation '+' we have 42+17 = 59
                For operation '-' we have 42-17 = 25

                [using typedef] For operation '-' we have 42-17 = 25
```

#### the code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int add(int, int);
int subtract(int, int);

typedef int (*t_VFT)(int, int);

int main(void)
{
    int (*VFT[256])(int, int) = {0};
    VFT['+'] = add;
    VFT['-'] = subtract;

    int  oper1 = 42;
    int  oper2 = 17;
    char op    = 0;
    printf(
        "\t\tOperands are '%d' and '%d'\n", oper1, oper2);

    op = '+';
    printf(
        "\t\tFor operation '%c' we have %d%c%d = %d\n", op,
        oper1, op, oper2, VFT[op](oper1, oper2));

    op = '-';
    printf(
        "\t\tFor operation '%c' we have %d%c%d = %d\n", op,
        oper1, op, oper2, VFT[op](oper1, oper2));

    t_VFT other_VFT[12];  // just an example using typedef
    other_VFT[11] = subtract;
    int res       = other_VFT[11](oper1, oper2);
    printf(
        "\n\t\t[using typedef] For operation '%c' we have %d%c%d = %d\n", '-',
        oper1, '-', oper2, res);

    return 0;
}

int add(int a, int b) { return a + b; }
int subtract(int a, int b) { return a - b; }

// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77161800
// /function-pointers-and-argurments
```

#### in short

This is the VFT being constructed:

```
    int (*VFT[256])(int, int) = {0};
    VFT['+'] = add;
    VFT['-'] = subtract;
```

This is the VFT being used:

```
    op = '-';
    printf(
        "\t\tFor operation '%c' we have %d%c%d = %d\n", op,
        oper1, op, oper2, VFT[op](oper1, oper2));
```

**NOTES:**

- writing     `int result = VFT[op](oper1,oper2)` calls **ALWAYS** the required function.
- the table can be changed at will, so one can replace the functions at any will. This is not the case with `operation()`:

```
int (*operation(char op))(int, int) {
  if (op == '+') {
      return &add;
  } else if (op == '-') {
      return &subtract;
  } else {
      return NULL;
  }
}
```

where we need to recompiled the code to change anything...